# jquery popup window position firefox issue

Tags: jquery, popup

I have a jquery popup window script on my site. It works fine in chrome but in firefox when the window is opened, it appears right at the top, where I want it to appear vertically more centered. Eg.

```
 ________________________
|     |           |     |
|     |   popup   |     |
|     |           |     |
|     |___________|     |
|                       |
|_______________________|
```

The script in popup.js:

```
function centerPopup(){
  var windowWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
  var windowHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
  var windowTop =window.screenTop;
  var popupHeight = $(".popupContent").height();
  var popupWidth = $(".popupContent").width();

  $(".popupContent").css({
    "position": "fixed",
    "top": (windowTop+250)-popupHeight/2,
    "left": windowWidth/2-popupWidth/2
    });

  //this is needed for ie6
  $(".backgroundPopup").css({ "position": "fixed", "height": windowHeight, "top": windowTop });
  }
```

Can anyone offer any suggestions what I need to change to get it working correct?

### UPDATE

The code above is from the popup.js script, there's also a popup.css, im not sure if anything in this part of it is conflicting or causing a problem

```
   .popupContent{
display:none;
align: center;
position: fixed;
_position: fixed; 
height:auto;
width:500px;
background:#fff;
z-index:9999;
padding:8px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-khtml-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
background-color: #15150B;
border:2px solid #C9C58F;
}
```

Comment: What does it do if you remove the `align:center;`?

Comment: i tried that before, nothing unfortunately :/

Comment: Can you create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that includes your html, css, and javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You should specifically set the top and left values to 50%, and you then need to set the margin-top and margin-left values to the height and widths values divided by -2. Note, you should also reuse your `$(".popupContent")` since you are using it more than once.

```
function centerPopup(){
    var windowWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    var windowHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    var windowTop =window.screenTop;
    var $popup = $(".popupContent");
    var popupHeight = $popup.height();
    var popupWidth = $popup.width();

    $popup.css({
        "position": "fixed",
        "top": "50%",
        "left": "50%",
        "z-index": "100",
        "width": popupWidth,              // Set the width of the popup
        "height": popupHeight,            // Set the height of the popup
        "margin-top": (popupHeight / -2), // Note this value is half the height
        "margin-left": (popupWidth / -2)  // Note this value is half the width
    });

    // IE6 hack :P
    $(".backgroundPopup").css({ "position": "fixed", "height": windowHeight, "top": windowTop });
}
```

Otherwise if you do not mind using a plugin to handle your popups, I would recommend the [modal popup plugin](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) provided in the jquery UI. It makes it really simple to create popups. You can do something as simple as the following:

```
$(function() {
    // Create a modal from an existing div
    $("#div_MyDialog").dialog();

    // OR Create a modal from input html
    $('<div id="div_MyDialog">My new dialog</div>').dialog();  
});
```

Comment: Can you create an example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that portrays the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I use this code to open a basic popup in the center of the window:

http://jsfiddle.net/hsgtA/

```
var w = 800;
var h = 500;
var left = (screen.width / 2) - (w / 2);
var top = (screen.height / 2) - (h / 2);
var target_win = window.open ('http://google.com', false, 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width='+ w +', height='+ h +', top='+ top +', left='+ left);
```